# multipart Identifier cound not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I reviewed several of the post on this subject and haven't been able to see resolve this error.  I have linked server that I'm trying to included in my WHERE clause in SQL 2008.  I was able to successfully execute the query with out the WHERE clause. I'm sure that I overlooked something just need some advice. The message for the multipart identifier is on this line in the WHERE clause.

LAWNURSEDB.NGDemo.dbo.EXPORT_DIRECTTIME.SocialSecurityNumber

```
SELECT     dbo.VP_PUNCHORIGIN.PERSONNUM, EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_1.SocialSecurityNumber,         dbo.VP_PUNCHORIGIN.PERSONFULLNAME
FROM         dbo.VP_PUNCHORIGIN INNER JOIN
                  LAWNURSEDB.NGDemo.dbo.EXPORT_DIRECTTIME AS EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_1 ON 
                  dbo.VP_PUNCHORIGIN.PERSONNUM = EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_1.SocialSecurityNumber
WHERE     (dbo.VP_PUNCHORIGIN.PERSONNUM NOT IN
                      (SELECT     LAWNURSEDB.NGDemo.dbo.EXPORT_DIRECTTIME.SocialSecurityNumber AS Expr1
                        FROM          LAWNURSEDB.NGDemo.dbo.EXPORT_DIRECTTIME AS EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using an alias in the `WHERE` clause subquery but don't reference it:

```
SELECT p.PERSONNUM, 
    EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_1.SocialSecurityNumber,         
    p.PERSONFULLNAME
FROM dbo.VP_PUNCHORIGIN p
INNER JOIN LAWNURSEDB.NGDemo.dbo.EXPORT_DIRECTTIME AS EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_1 
    ON p.PERSONNUM = EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_1.SocialSecurityNumber
WHERE p.PERSONNUM 
         NOT IN (SELECT EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_2.SocialSecurityNumber 
                 FROM LAWNURSEDB.NGDemo.dbo.EXPORT_DIRECTTIME AS EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_2)
```

Comment: Oh yeh forgot to reference that I removed the alias all together and used the fullname for the link server.  Still get the same message.

Comment: @user1966966 do you get the error if you remove the alias on the `EXPORT_DIRECTTIME_2.SocialSecurityNumber`?

Comment: Yes I remove the alias from each clause representing that linked server connection.

Comment: @user1966966 if this answer helped you solve your problem then consider accepting via the checkmark on the left of it. It will help future visitors to the site and you will get rep for accepting.